# How to hide browser URL using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

**Question:**

How to hide browser URL using codeigniter?

**My Current URL:**

```
http://localhost/civicsoft_local/index.php/civic_soft_control/login?state=0
```

**Expected URL:**

```
http://localhost/civicsoft_local/
```

**CodeIgniter .htaccess file content as follows:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(ci_civic_soft\index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ci_civic_soft/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to enable Query Strings
check this http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

if you need to more
check this
http://www.web-and-development.com/codeigniter-remove-index-php-minimize-url/

Comment: hi frnd i am beginner in codeIgniter. So please tell me exact thing.

Comment: in my given tutorial

first replace your existing content in the .htaccess from 1st step code

Answer (score 0):

1. Edit Query Strings in config file .

   ```
    $config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
   ```
2. In route change your default URL

   ```
   $route['default_controller'] = "civic_soft_control/login/0";
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) installed and enabled and put this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

In your `applicaiton/config/config.php` file make sure it has this:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Comment: how to install mod_rewrite and which REQUEST_FILENAME and REQUEST_URI, i have to mention. Plz tell me i am beginner in codeigniter

Comment: You need all of that text in your .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that in your .htaccess file you have the below.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
```

Now in your config.php file you want to ensure that you have the below

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Finally in your routes file you have to map the shortened version of the url to the controller/function.

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'civic_soft_control/name_of_funtion';
```